# Calculated field and creating pie chart/donut using this calculated field

Tags: tableau-api, donut-chart

I have this following table

```
| Name | Group | Group1 | Group2 | Course  | Completed |
|------|-------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|
| abc  | Engg  | Civil  | single | engg1   | y         |
| abc  | Engg  | Civil  | single | math123 | y         |
| abc  | Engg  | Civil  | single | advmath | y         |
| def  | Engg  | Mech   | single | engg1   | y         |
| def  | Engg  | Mech   | single | math123 | n         |
| def  | Engg  | Mech   | single | advmath | y         |
| ghi  | Engg  | Civil  | double | engg1   | y         |
| ghi  | Engg  | Civil  | double | math123 | n         |
| ghi  | Engg  | Civil  | double | advmath | n         |
| ijk  | Engg  | Mech   | double | engg1   | y         |
| ijk  | Engg  | Mech   | double | math123 | y         |
| ijk  | Engg  | Mech   | double | advmath | y         |
```

I am trying to create a pie/donut chart to show % of students that have not completed all the course.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare completed = y versus completed = n simply:

- create a new sheet
- double click on the completed field (to add it to the sheet)
- double click on [Number of Records] (to add it to the sheet)
- Click on Show Me (top right) and choose pie graph

It should look like this in the end ....  [image]

EDIT: ah ok, I understand the data now, here's the result by creating 2 calculated fields:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you cmcau. What I want is to show % of students who have not completed all the courses. In this   case 50% of students haven't completed.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the names being the same (and meaningful), I've added to my answer to do an LOD to figure out what the student did and then a further calculation to turn that back into y/n for the legend.

Comment: Thanks, can you mark the answer as correct as well please ?

Comment: Nice answer. FYI, you can simplify by returning a Boolean instead of a string,  defining Fully Completed as { FIXED [Name] : MIN([Completed] = ‘y’) }. Min() for Boolean can be read as All?()